# How to add n number of items in listbox from an array of XY coordinates

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I have an image of blobs whose COG I converted into an array of XY coordinates Apoints[i]. I want to add these coordiinates into a listbox. Depending on the image there can be from 0 to maximum 300 XY points. I have a syntax in which I want to add them as follows :

```
P1 = (Y,X,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)(0,0)
P2 = (Y,X,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)(0,0)
.
.
.
P300 = (Y,X,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)(0,0)
```

each in a new line in listbox

But points can be anywhere from 0 to 300 and is not fixed, it depends on the image. Some image might have o points, so no need to add. Some image might have 20 points, so I need P1 to P20. I dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I assume

- you can use a loop to iterate over `Apoints[]`
- `Apoint[i]` has an `X` and `Y` properties
- "P1 = (Y,X,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)(0,0)" is a string
- you can compute somehow the number of points for your image

Just tell me if I'm wrong...

Then you can do something like this:

```
var n = GetNumberOfPointsInImage()
for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
  var y = Apoints[i].y;
  var x = Apoints[i].x;
  var p = $"P{i} = ({y},{x},0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)(0,0)";
  myListBox.Items.Add(p);
}
```

Comment: it gives an error that ";" expected in $"P{i} = ({y},{x},0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)(0,0)";